# RSA Fast exponentiation

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, cryptography

I am reading a book on cryptography - A mathematical introduction to cryptography (Hoffstein et. al, 1st Edition) and through chapter 3.2, I found this...[image]

which describes the RSA system. The author then describes how we could choose $e$.The author says most people who want fast encryption uses $e=2^{16}+1$ as it only takes 4 squarings and one multiplication to compute $m^e$.

I understand the part the it takes one multiplication as $m^{2^{16}+1}=m^{2^{16}}\times m$. But I can not understand how $m^{2^{16}}$ only takes 4 squaring...

I was thinking like this $a_1=m^2$, $a_2=a_1^2=m^4$ , $a_3=a_2^2=m^8$ and $a_4=a_3^2=m^{16}$. This clearly is not correct as $2^{16}\neq16$. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography @kelalaka

Comment: Hoffstein, Jeffrey, Pipher, Jill, Silverman, J.H. and page 121 @kelalaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before reading a book, one should look for the [errata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erratum). In older times, it was hard to get an errata before a second edition. Now, in the internet era, they are collected online, usually [from the page of the author](http://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/MathCryptoHome.html)

Now the errata says;

> **Page 121, Line 17**
>
> “since it takes only four squarings and one multiplication to compute $m^{65537}$ should be “since it takes only sixteen squarings and one multiplication to compute $m^{65537}$”.

Note that $65537 = 2^{16}+1$ and it is the 4th Fermat prime ($F_4 = 2^{2^4}+1$)

Why do we choose $e$ as a small prime?

1. We can guarantee that $\gcd(e, \varphi(n)) =1$
2. The total number of squaring and multiplications is small, especially in Fermat primes.

Comment: *Before reading a book, one should look for the errata.* Upvoted this.

Comment: @WhatsUp A personal experience: During my MS.C. my professor gave me a book from Birkhauser. It was full of errors. I've couldn't find an errata, and saw some of the errors to my prof, and they were shocked to see such a book from Birkhauser. I don't remember the book. If one day, I could go to see them, I will look at the book on the shelves.

Comment: Good advice, thanks! ;)

Comment: A common occurrence alas, as publishers do not have enough qualified staff to actually proof read a book beforehand. They did do that in the old days (when the had to typeset everything too) which added a lot of costs. Nowadays they just get print ready postscript from LaTeX and they’ve become lazy IMO.

Comment: [Knuth's Reward Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check) was a very clever idea to find the errors.

Answer (score 2):

The author has made a mistake. It takes $16$ squarings, not $4$.

Comment: $e=17$ is also a common choice and there the numbers fit.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma there is an errata for the edition. not 4 squaring, [16 squarings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283383/338051).

Comment: @kelalaka I agree we need $16$ squarings . But maybe the authors had $17$ in mind originally, was my suggestion...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, I'm aware of it that is why I want to warn you about the errata, however, 65537 is more common than 17 in the libraries and that will change more parts of the text than a single word, I tend on 65537 and four was the mistake.